# Unable to move a shape in processing

Tags: processing, p5.js

I am attempting to create a movable entity who can move left and right on a map. I have a map that sets the initial location of the entity but once the 'a' or 'd' keys are pushed, the character moves only slightly then resets to its initial location once the key is released. I have a Boolean variable "playerIsSpawned" to ensure that the character's location is only set in that location once, however this didn't seem to fix anything. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
var start_map = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];
var playerX;
var playerY;

function drawPlayer() {
  fill(0);
  rect(playerX, playerY, 50, 50);
}

function drawMap(map) {
  // The x and y do not represent the x and y axis
  // Keep in mind a 2d array is an array of an array
  noStroke();
  var playerIsSpawned = false;

  for (var x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
      // Background
      if (map[y][x] == 0) {
        fill(184, 236, 255);
        rect((10 + 50*x), (10 + 50*y), 50, 50);
      }
      // Ground
      else if (map[y][x] == 1) {
        fill(51, 153, 51);
        rect((10 + 50*x), (10 + 50*y), 50, 50);
      }
      // Player
      else if (map[y][x] == 9) {
        if (playerIsSpawned == false) {
          playerX = (10 + 50*x);
          playerY = (10 + 50*y);
          playerIsSpawned = true;
        }
        fill(184, 236, 255);
        rect((10 + 50*x), (10 + 50*y), 50, 50);
      }
    }
  }
  drawPlayer();
  function keyPressed() {
    if (key == "d") {
      playerX += 5;
    }
    else if (key == "a") {
      playerX -= 5;
    }
  }
  keyPressed();
}

function setup() {
  background(0);
  createCanvas(800, 800);
}

function draw() {
  drawMap(start_map);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely not [Processing](https://processing.org) code, because Processing code uses Java syntax. Are you using Processing.js, or maybe P5.js?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is p5.js -- which is part of the Processing family. I added the `p5.js` tag, but think that it is appropriate to keep the `processing` tag as well since p5.js is basically a JavaScript port of Processing.

Comment: Speaking as the main developer for Processing.js: it really, really isn't. Processing.js is a straight syntax and API compatible port, P5.js is "what if we had to do Processing again, but we used JS as basis". It's completely different (even if it _is_ really cool) =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your work. I've tended to think of Processing.js as in many ways *better* than a port of Processing to JavaScript: it is a magic library that allows (most) Processing sketches to be run as is in a browser rather than the JVM. On the other hand, p5.js is what you get when you try a more direct port of the key functions (`draw()`, `rect()` etc.) to JavaScript. Both projects are impressive and both have a role to play in the Processing world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `playerIsSpawned` inside `drawMap`.  That'll get reset to `false` every time through there.

Also, consider defining the `keyPressed()` at the top level (same as `draw` and `setup`, and getting rid of that call to `keyPressed()` inside your `draw` loop.